# Knockout JS inside table collapse two columns depending on visibility

Tags: html, knockout.js, html-table, knockout-mvc

I'm pretty new in Knockout JS binding and I have this table which is supposed to be a row with a single column with the button if the `Confirmed` text is empty and two separate columns in other way.

Here is what I've tried so far,

```
<table class="table" id="Mytable" style="table-layout: fixed;">
       <tbody data-bind="foreach: info">
              <tr>
                 <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
                     <button type="button" class="btn2 btn-default" data-bind="click:$root.getClick, trimText:shortName, trimTextLength: 5, css: Confirmed == '' ? colspan='2' : ''">22</button>
                 </td>
                 <td style="vertical-align:middle">
                      <span style="color:green" data-bind="text: Confirmed, visible: Confirmed != ''">10</span>
                 </td>
              </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

but it seems that it doesn't display the info correctly and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Please be gentle with me, I'm trying to learn from mistakes.

Comment: Could you show your JS as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`colspan` is an attribute, which you set using the `attr` binding:

```
 data-bind="attr: { 'colspan': Confirmed() ? 1 : 2 }"
```

In your specific case, I'd use a virtual `if` binding to switch between the two cases:

```html
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: info">
    <tr>
      <!-- ko if: Confirmed -->
      <td colspan="2">
        <button type="button" 
                data-bind="click:$root.getClick, trimText:shortName, trimTextLength: 5">22</button>
      </td>
      <!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko ifnot: Confirmed -->
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="text: Confirmed"></span>
      </td>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```